# Showing order confirmation after online food ordering

Tags: feedback, confirmation, shopping-cart

I am developing an online food ordering platform. It has the following steps.
1. 1st Screen: Menu from where user add food to cart
2. Second Screen: Give payment info
3. 3rd Screen: Review and submit order

Now after ordering is place I take user back to menu page. Now I want to give user confirmation that he order has been accepted. I am thinking of popup or flash message with a timer but as I am not an UX designer I am not sure. Can anyone here please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just take the user to a confirmation page after submitting the order?

Comment: what the text should displaying on confirmation message ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when users submit something they expect a response, and they expect this response to match their inquiry. When users submit their order they expect to be told whether it was submitted successfully or not, not taken back to the menu.

If you think of the process analogous to a real food order how would you feel if the clerk took your payment and then handed you a menu instead of a receipt, you would be confused.

So to keep the expected flow for the user I would lead to another confirmation page right after the Review and Submit page. From here you could have a redirect link back to the menu. This allows the user to stay on the page as long as they need in case they want to print the receipt for their own records.

Comment: what the text should displaying on confirmation message ?